# Pandas groupby with extra category column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have to adapt this code for a new requirement. Essentially it creates a dataframe with a column 'group'
that follows this rule: The last day of the year will be used as the first and last element of the group,
and  that will be used in a group by. But the requirement now has changed adding a category level for the dataframe.

This code was the original solution:

```
data = {'date':  ['2017-03-31', '2017-04-03', '2017-12-27', '2017-12-28',
                    '2017-12-29', '2018-01-02', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-02',
                    '2019-01-03', '2019-12-31', '2020-12-30', '2020-12-31',
                    '2021-01-20', '2021-12-30', '2021-12-31', '2022-05-30',
                    '2022-05-31'],
        'value': [1163.00, 1221.15, 1318.84, 1384.78,
                    1523.26, 1660.36, 1710.17, 1881.18,
                    1956.43, 2015.12, 2216.64, 2349.63,
                    2373.13, 2562.98, 2819.28, 2875.66,
                    2904.42 ]          
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
d = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
dup = d.dt.year.ne(d.shift().dt.year).shift(-1, fill_value=False).add(1)
df1 = df1.reindex(df1.index.repeat(dup))
gid = df1.index.duplicated(keep='first').cumsum() + 1
df1 = df1.assign(group=gid).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The output as expected:

```
          date    value group
0   2017-03-31  1163.00     1
1   2017-04-03  1221.15     1
2   2017-12-27  1318.84     1
3   2017-12-28  1384.78     1
4   2017-12-29  1523.26     1
5   2017-12-29  1523.26     2
6   2018-01-02  1660.36     2
7   2018-12-31  1710.17     2
8   2018-12-31  1710.17     3
9   2019-01-02  1881.18     3
10  2019-01-03  1956.43     3
11  2019-12-31  2015.12     3
12  2019-12-31  2015.12     4
13  2020-12-30  2216.64     4
14  2020-12-31  2349.63     4
15  2020-12-31  2349.63     5
16  2021-01-20  2373.13     5
17  2021-12-30  2562.98     5
18  2021-12-31  2819.28     5
19  2021-12-31  2819.28     6
20  2022-05-30  2875.66     6
21  2022-05-31  2904.42     6
```

But the requirement has changed. I have a category level. I created the following cartesian product
for the sake of simplicity but in real world categories will have its own dates and values:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Cat': ['Cat1', 'Cat2']})
df3 = pd.merge(df2.assign(key=1), df1.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
```

the desired output would be:

```
     Cat          date    value group
0   Cat1    2017-03-31  1163.00     1
1   Cat1    2017-04-03  1221.15     1
2   Cat1    2017-12-27  1318.84     1
3   Cat1    2017-12-28  1384.78     1
4   Cat1    2017-12-29  1523.26     1
5   Cat1    2017-12-29  1523.26     2
6   Cat1    2018-01-02  1660.36     2
7   Cat1    2018-12-31  1710.17     2
8   Cat1    2018-12-31  1710.17     3
9   Cat1    2019-01-02  1881.18     3
10  Cat1    2019-01-03  1956.43     3
11  Cat1    2019-12-31  2015.12     3
12  Cat1    2019-12-31  2015.12     4
13  Cat1    2020-12-30  2216.64     4
14  Cat1    2020-12-31  2349.63     4
15  Cat1    2020-12-31  2349.63     5
16  Cat1    2021-01-20  2373.13     5
17  Cat1    2021-12-30  2562.98     5
18  Cat1    2021-12-31  2819.28     5
19  Cat1    2021-12-31  2819.28     6
20  Cat1    2022-05-30  2875.66     6
21  Cat1    2022-05-31  2904.42     6
22  Cat2    2017-03-31  1163.00     1
23  Cat2    2017-04-03  1221.15     1
24  Cat2    2017-12-27  1318.84     1
25  Cat2    2017-12-28  1384.78     1
26  Cat2    2017-12-29  1523.26     1
27  Cat2    2017-12-29  1523.26     2
28  Cat2    2018-01-02  1660.36     2
29  Cat2    2018-12-31  1710.17     2
30  Cat2    2018-12-31  1710.17     3
31  Cat2    2019-01-02  1881.18     3
32  Cat2    2019-01-03  1956.43     3
33  Cat2    2019-12-31  2015.12     3
34  Cat2    2019-12-31  2015.12     4
35  Cat2    2020-12-30  2216.64     4
36  Cat2    2020-12-31  2349.63     4
37  Cat2    2020-12-31  2349.63     5
38  Cat2    2021-01-20  2373.13     5
39  Cat2    2021-12-30  2562.98     5
40  Cat2    2021-12-31  2819.28     5
41  Cat2    2021-12-31  2819.28     6
42  Cat2    2022-05-30  2875.66     6
43  Cat2    2022-05-31  2904.42     6
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the result expected as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def group(g):
    gid = []
    d = pd.to_datetime(g['data'])
    dup = d.dt.year.ne(d.shift().dt.year).shift(-1, fill_value=False).add(1)
    g = g.reindex(g.index.repeat(dup))
    gid = g.index.duplicated(keep='first').cumsum() + 1
    g = g.assign(group=gid).reset_index(drop=True)
    return g

def v1(g):
    first, last = g['value'].values[[0,-1]]
    return last/first-1 if first > 0 else 0

data = {'date':  ['2017-03-31', '2017-04-03', '2017-12-27', '2017-12-28',
                '2017-12-29', '2018-01-02', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-02',
                '2019-01-03', '2019-12-31', '2020-12-30', '2020-12-31',
                '2021-01-20', '2021-12-30', '2021-12-31', '2022-05-30',
                '2022-05-31'],
    'value': [1163.00, 1221.15, 1318.84, 1384.78,
                1523.26, 1660.36, 1710.17, 1881.18,
                1956.43, 2015.12, 2216.64, 2349.63,
                2373.13, 2562.98, 2819.28, 2875.66,
                2904.42 ]          
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['Cat1', 'Cat2']})
df = pd.merge(df2.assign(key=1), df.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.sort_values(by=['cat','date'], inplace=True)
res = df.groupby(['cat']).apply(lambda g: group(g))
res.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) 

grouped = res.groupby(['cat', 'group']).apply(lambda g: [v1(g)])

out = pd.DataFrame(grouped.tolist(), index=grouped.index, columns=['Retorno']).reset_index()

print(out)
```